# Using fsolve to find the price necessary for two averages to intersect in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to create a function in Python to solve for the value needed for two moving averages, across two datasets of differing lengths, to be equal.  For example, the datasets

```
5
2
34
54
5
Average = 14
```

and

```
7
4
11
5
56
7
8
Average = 20
```

I want to solve for some number X that sets them both equal to the same average.  I believe the `fsolve` function in scipy can do this easily, but the catch is that I want to do this using something analogous to pandas' `.rolling` function, so that this formula can be applied on a rolling dataset moving through thousands of rows of data.

So, I'm envisioning some function like the below, though obviously it doesn't work.  To clarify, count_ variables have a + 1 because I'm envisioning only looking at a the trailing set of data that is -1 of the actual average set I'm looking to find.  Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
def equations(short_ma, long_ma, p):
    sum_short = short_ma.sum()
    sum_long = long_ma.sum()
    count_short = short_ma.count() + 1
    count_long = long_ma.count() + 1
    ptv, eq_var = p
    return (((sum_short + ptv) / count_short) - eq_var, ((sum_long + ptv) / count_long) - eq_var)

def rolling_equations(ptv, eq_var):
    ptv, eq_var = fsolve(equations, (1,1))
    return ptv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, effectively modeled off of @kabanus suggestions.  Note I have another module called arguments1 that imports variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from arguments1 import *

def common_value_solver(range):
    short_ma = arguments1.short_ma
    long_ma = arguments1.long_ma
    sum_short = range.tail(short_ma-1).sum()
    sum_long = range.tail(long_ma-1).sum()
    count_short = short_ma_arg
    count_long = long_ma_arg
    ptv = ((count_long * sum_short) - (count_short * sum_long) / (count_short - count_long))
    return ptv
```

Comment: Nice. Do not forget to accept your answer, for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a numerical solver to solve one linear equation of one variable (also, if its a linear system of equations you should use `linalg`, but that only starts from two equations). If you want

```
(a.sum()+eqVar)/(a.size+1) == (b.sum()+eqVar)/(b.size+1)
```

then

```
eqVar == (b.sum()/(b.size()+1)-a.sum()/(a.size+1))/(1/(a.size+1)-1/(b.size+1)) ==
      == (b.sum()/(b.size()+1)-a.sum()/(a.size+1))*((a.size+1)(b.size+1)/(a.size-b.size)) ==
      == ((a.size+1)*b.sum()-(b.size+1)*a.sum())/(a.size-b.size)
```

If I did not get my math wrong. To make it simpler, lets assume you only want to add a value to the first column to equate them (you can double check and use the above  if you want):

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd

def eqVar(df):
    a = df[0] 
    b = df[1] 
    return b.sum()*(a.size+1)/b.size-a.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20).reshape(-1,2))
df.rolling(4).apply(eqVar)
```

you could one line that for less clarity:

```
df.rolling(4).apply(lambda d: d[1].sum()*(d[0].size+1)/d[1].size-d[0].sum())
```

Comment: Hi @kabanus, thank you for your reply.  I definitely understand what you're saying about not needing a solver when the two equations can be set equal to one another.  My one question, especially the .rolling() portion, is how that .rolling(4) differentiates for the different lengths of the two different moving averages needed?  For instance, if I have df["end_of_month"], and I'm looking for a 20 period and 100 period rolling moving average to be applied to the function, would the function require the difference i.e. df.rolling(80)?  I'm very green with programming, thank you again!

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from how to deal with the two different .sum() lengths - as the rolling function needs to sum both the last 20 and the last 100 rows.